# Как получить rusage из id процесса?

Tags: windows, golang, ос

У меня есть код который запускает какую-то системную команду, и получает id этого процесса:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {   
    cmd := strings.Join(os.Args[1:], " ")

    p := exec.Command("cmd.exe", "/C", cmd)
    
    p.Start()
    pid := p.Process.Pid

    fmt.Println(pid)
}
```

И далее мне надо получить с помощью этого `pid` структуру `Rusage`, она есть в модуле `golang.org/x/sys/windows`, но функции для её получения я не нашёл.

UPD: Можно получать какую-нибудь другую структуру содержащую ту-же информацию.

PS: Всё это делается под windows.

В интернете искал много, но что-то ничего подходящего не нашёл.

PPS: Я знаю про [github.com/shirou/gopsutil](https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil), но там что-то тоже ничего такого нету :(

Comment: А разве rusage это не про linux? Если надо что-то подобное, если я правильно понял, то вот здесь вроде есть как это делается в исходниках PostgreSQL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62251386/converting-getrusage-from-linux-to-windows там на Си, но можно и перевести в Golang

Comment: @NormanBytes нет, есть `rusage` и для windows: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows#Rusage

Comment: Пакет gopsutils предоставляет функцию [getProcessCPUTimes](https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil/blob/5ee64c61906c12a703c58da97fbfc4a513cd5d06/process/process_windows.go#L923). Она делает именно то что вам нужно, ИМХО

Comment: @PakUula она же начинается с маленькой буквы, а значит она приватная... :(

Comment: То есть нет обертки для getrusage из /sys/resource.h ? Похоже, по любому придется использование API, можно и через windows.OpenProcess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, функция приватная, но творческий рерайтинг никто не отменял :)

```go
func GetRusage(pid uint32) (syscall.Rusage, error) {
    h, err := windows.OpenProcess(windows.PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, false, pid)
    if err != nil {
        return syscall.Rusage{}, err
    }
    defer windows.CloseHandle(h)

    var rusage syscall.Rusage

    err = syscall.GetProcessTimes(
        syscall.Handle(h),
        &rusage.CreationTime,
        &rusage.ExitTime,
        &rusage.KernelTime,
        &rusage.UserTime,
    )
    return rusage, err
}
```

**UPDATE**

Как преобразовать `Filetime` в удобочитаемую строку

```
const (
    // FileTime "тикает" с периодом 100 нс
    TICK_NS          int64 = 100
    TICKS_PER_SECOND int64 = 10000000
    // FileTime отсчитывает тики с 1 января 1601 года
    // EPOCH_DIFFERENCE_SEC равно числу секунд между 1 января 1601 года и 1 января 1970 года
    EPOCH_DIFFERENCE_SEC   int64 = 11644473600
    EPOCH_DIFFERENCE_TICKS int64 = EPOCH_DIFFERENCE_SEC * TICKS_PER_SECOND
)

func FileTimeToString(t syscall.Filetime) string {
    var ticks uint64
    ticks = uint64(t.HighDateTime)<<32 + uint64(t.LowDateTime)
    unixTicks := int64(ticks) - EPOCH_DIFFERENCE_TICKS
    unixTime := time.Unix(unixTicks/TICKS_PER_SECOND, (unixTicks%TICKS_PER_SECOND)*TICK_NS)
    return unixTime.String()
}
```

Comment: Да конечно я понимаю, я получил структуру rusage, но почему всё кроме `CreationTime` равно нулю? И что в этом `CreationTime` вообще записано?

Comment: @чистов_n `ExitTime` равен нулю, так как процесс ещё не завершился. Про остальные времена не знаю. Подробности здесь: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocesstimes . `Filetime` - это 64-х битный счётчик 100-наносекундных тиков, начиная с 1 января 1601 года по григорианскому календарю. Пример, как его можно преобразовать в строку и распечатать добавил в ответ.